# Literature on nonparametric contrasts

Tags: references, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test, contrasts

I am wondering how I can perform and interpret contrasts in a particular case described below.
I am comparing three independent groups which are not normally distributed (heavily), thus I have opted for Kruskal-Wallis test and tested for equality of distributions. The result is significant and I detected a pairwise difference. Still, I do not know how to test a contrast that is particularly intereting for me, i.e. one group against the other two. When it comes to ANOVA it is simple and easily interpretable, i.e. posting a question whether a particular linear combination of means is significantly different from zero. But in the case of nonparametric test, the issue is confusing for me. I did a research on the Internet in search for any hint but have not found anything relevant. Can anyone recommend any relevant literature?

Comment: Of possible interest: [Post hoc comparisons for the Kruskal-Wallis test](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/post-hoc-comparisons-kruskal-wallis-test).

Comment: The KW test doesn't test if the distributions are equal.  It tests if any are stochastically greater than any others.  Ie, am I likely to get a larger value if I pick an observation at random from one group than another group. Is that what you want?